# How do I initialize an observable property in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I find this very puzzling. Coming from ReactiveCocoa I would expect something like this possible.

[image]

How can I initialize the RxSwift observable to 5?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create stream in multiple ways:

**Main way**

```
    Observable<Int>.create { observer -> Disposable in

        // Send events through observer
        observer.onNext(3)
        observer.onError(NSError(domain: "", code: 1, userInfo: nil))
        observer.onCompleted()

        return Disposables.create {
            // Clean up when stream is deallocated
        }
    }
```

**Shortcuts**

```
    Observable<Int>.empty() // Completes straight away
    Observable<Int>.never() // Never gets any event into the stream, waits forever
    Observable<Int>.just(1) // Emit value "1" and completes
```

**Through Subjects** (aka `Property` / `MutableProperty` in ReactiveSwift)

*`Variable` is deprecated in RxSwift 4, but it's just a wrapper around BehaviourSubject, so you can use it instead.*

There are 2 most used subjects

`BehaviorSubject` - it will emit current value and upcoming ones. Because it will emit current value it needs to be initialised with a value `BehaviorSubject<Int>(value: 0)`

`PublishSubject` - it will emit upcoming values. It doesn't require initial value while initialising `PublishSubject<Int>()`

Then you can call `.asObservable()` on subject instance to get an observable.

Answer (score 2):

In RxSwift `Variable` is deprecated.  Use `BehaviorRelay` or `BehaviorSubject`

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to test it right now, but wouldn't `Observable.just` be the function you are looking for?

Source for Observable creation: [github link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Observables/Observable%2BCreation.swift)

Of course, you could also use a `Variable(5)` if you intend to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

As I am learning RxSwift I ran up on this thread. You can initialize an observable property like this:

```
var age = Variable<Int>(5)
```

And set it up as an observable:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

private func setupAgeObserver() {
    age.asObservable()
      .subscribe(onNext: {
        years in
        print ("age is \(years)")
        // do something
      })
      .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
 }
```

Comment: Variable is no longer there in RxSwift

Answer (score 0):

in Rx in general, there is a BehaviorSubject which stores the last value

specifically in RxSwift, there is also Variable which is a wrapper around BehaviorSubject

see description of both here - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md